# How to fade out a set of HTML elements and then 1 of them fades in with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

Seems simple enough. I want an all `<div>`s to `fadeOut()` and then 1 of the `<div>`s to `fadeIn()`. But I get crazy behavior with something like this ([jsfiddle with 3 `<div>`s](http://jsfiddle.net/Tdv2U/))

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('div').fadeOut(2000, function() {$('div#first').fadeIn();}); return false;">Show first div</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="$('div').fadeOut(2000, function() {$('div#second').fadeIn();}); return false;">Show second div</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="$('div').fadeOut(2000, function() {$('div#third').fadeIn();}); return false;">Show third div</a>
<br/>
<div style="display:none" id="first">First div</div>
<div style="display:none" id="second">Second div</div>
<div style="display:none" id="third">Third div</div>
```

Sometimes the old div and the new div will disappear. Sometimes the new div will appear, fade and then reappear.

I think what's happening is when all `div`s `fadeOut`, ***each*** one of them calls the `fadeIn` function and that gets a little screwy. So what's a solution here to `fadeIn` only **after** all have been faded out?

Comment: Please also put your code into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your callback gets called 3 times, one for each matched div after the animation for that div completes.

Here is an excerpt from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/):

> Callback Function
>
> If supplied, the callback is fired once the animation is complete.
>   This can be useful for stringing different animations together in
>   sequence. The callback is not sent any arguments, but this is set to
>   the DOM element being animated. If multiple elements are animated, it
>   is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched
>   element, not once for the animation as a whole.
>
> As of jQuery 1.6, the .promise() method can be used in conjunction
>   with the deferred.done() method to execute a single callback for the
>   animation as a whole when all matching elements have completed their
>   animations ( See the example for .promise() ).

here is a solution to your problem:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('div').fadeOut(2000);$('div').promise().done(function() {$('div#first').fadeIn();}); return false;">Show first div</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="$('div').fadeOut(2000);$('div').promise().done(function() {$('div#second').fadeIn();}); return false;">Show second div</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="$('div').fadeOut(2000);$('div').promise().done(function() {$('div#third').fadeIn();}); return false;">Show third div</a>
<br/>
<div style="display:none" id="first">First div</div>
<div style="display:none" id="second">Second div</div>
<div style="display:none" id="third">Third div</div>
```

Comment: I'll have to check out those `promise()` and `done()` functions!